# how to store images from excel sheet in laravel 5

Tags: php, excel, image, laravel-5

i'm using [this library](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel) to upload excel files and store the data from  excel to database .. and i want to store images from excel to storage but not succeed .. this is my code

```
 public function addExcel(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
'file' => 'required'
    ]);
     Excel::load($request->file('file')->getRealPath(), function ($reader) {
         foreach ($reader->toArray() as $key => $row) {
                $data['model_name'] = $row['model_name'];
                $data['part_number'] = $row['part_number'];


                if(!empty($data)) {
                    DB::table('products')->insert($data);
                }
            }
     });
     return 'done';
}
```

[image: and this is my excel]

Answer (score 1):

It will be via native library used behind this package. For more info on how to get image from excel, this is their documentation link: https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/recipes/#reading-images-from-a-worksheet.

```
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getDrawingCollection() as $drawing) {
        if ($drawing instanceof \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\MemoryDrawing) {
            ob_start();
            call_user_func(
                $drawing->getRenderingFunction(),
                $drawing->getImageResource()
            );
            $imageContents = ob_get_contents();
            ob_end_clean();
            switch ($drawing->getMimeType()) {
                case \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\MemoryDrawing::MIMETYPE_PNG :
                    $extension = 'png';
                    break;
                case \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\MemoryDrawing::MIMETYPE_GIF:
                    $extension = 'gif';
                    break;
                case \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\MemoryDrawing::MIMETYPE_JPEG :
                    $extension = 'jpg';
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            $zipReader = fopen($drawing->getPath(),'r');
            $imageContents = '';
            while (!feof($zipReader)) {
                $imageContents .= fread($zipReader,1024);
            }
            fclose($zipReader);
            $extension = $drawing->getExtension();
        }
        $myFileName = '00_Image_'.++$i.'.'.$extension;
        file_put_contents($myFileName,$imageContents);
    }
```

Comment: yes this code it worked for images but how to save the data ?

Comment: The image data? or other data?

Comment: other data .. because the if statement always not executed but the else executed